# Sort method doesn't re-render cards in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, sorting, react-hooks

I get data from random profile API. Then I want to click a button and sort my profile cards by age or last name.

I got a sorted array in `console.log` in the `handle` function, but the UI didn`t change. I couldn`t understand what I do wrong. Any help would be appreciated

```
function App() {
  const baseURL = `https://randomuser.me/api`;
  const [profiles, setProfiles] = useState([]);
  const [singleProfile, setSingleProfile] = useState([]);

  const showProfiles = useCallback(() => {
    axios.get(baseURL).then((response) => {
      setProfiles(response.data.results);
    });
  }, [baseURL]);

  const showProfile = useCallback(() => {
    axios.get(baseURL).then((response) => {
      setSingleProfile(response.data.results);
    });
  }, [baseURL])

  useEffect(() => {
    showProfiles();
    showProfile();
  }, [showProfiles, showProfile]);

  const deleteProfile = (profileId) => {
    setProfiles(prevState => prevState.filter(profile => profile.id.value !== profileId))
  }

  const addProfile = () => {
    showProfile();
    setProfiles(prevState => [...prevState, ...singleProfile]);
  }

  const handleSortByAge = () => {
    const profilesSortedByAge = profiles.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.dob.age > b.dob.age) {
        return 1;
      } else {
        return -1;
      }
    })
    console.log('click and profiles', profiles);
    return setProfiles(profilesSortedByAge);
  }

  const handleSortByLastName = () => {
    const profilesSortedByLastName = profiles.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.name.last > b.name.last) {
        return 1;
      } else {
        return -1;
      }
    })
    setProfiles(profilesSortedByLastName);
  }

  if (!profiles) return null;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ProfilesPage
        profiles={profiles}
        showProfiles={showProfiles}
        deleteProfile={deleteProfile}
        addProfile={addProfile}
        setProfiles={setProfiles}
        handleSortByAge={handleSortByAge}
        handleSortByLastName={handleSortByLastName}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 3):

`Array.prototype.sort` does an in-place mutation of the array, a ***new*** array reference for React's reconciliation process was never created. Create a shallow copy first, *then* sort.

Example:

```
const handleSortByAge = () => {
  const profilesSortedByAge = profiles
    .slice()
    .sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.dob.age > b.dob.age) {
        return 1;
      } else {
        return -1;
      }
    })
  console.log('click and profiles', profiles);
  return setProfiles(profilesSortedByAge);
}
```

Comment: You just saved me! Thank you much, it works for me greate